# integrate WordPress functions into magento 2 store using WP-load function in magento root index.php

Tags: wordpress, magento2.4

I have multi-site WordPRESS website. https://staging3.rocknetworks.com/. So, I need to include my WordPress header & footer in magento 2 (Fresh magento 2) https://staging3.rocknetworks.com/store2 website.

I have added the wp-load.php in magento 2 root index.php but it's not working for me. https://prnt.sc/uc0o22

Basically I need to  use wordpress functions in magento 2 template so that i can create use same layout like my WordPress.

On My live website in which I have setup magento 1 which is working fine. but it's not working for magento 2.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a messy solution. Why not replicate the design of the blog header/footer theme in Magento rather than trying to shave a yak? If you need to get menu items have an API on the Wordpress site that Magento can query.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Thankyour for reply against my question. Yes! you are right! that proper way is to replicate the design in magento 2 like WordPress, but I want to find a way in which we can move all my CSS changes into Magento 2 just like I did for Magento 1